# Easiest/best way to view http POST and GET data in Eclipse? Any plugins / tools?

Tags: java, eclipse, http, httpwebrequest, monitor

My Eclipse is a SpringSource tool suite with Aptana 3 beta plugged in. It's a beast...but I can find out how I can monitor pure http POST en GET data.

There must me a way to start some kind of web server that just prints the pure request data I guess...

Someone can point me out to some nice solutions perhaps? (and the httpfox plugin doesn't work on Firefox 4)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found an easier way too, using SpringSource Toolsuite there is a built in feature:
right-clicking my web server and choosing monitoring.

Answer (score 3):

Fiddler works like charm for similar needs. See http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/

Answer (score 2):

LiveHTTPHeaders version 0.17 works on FF4.

http://livehttpheaders.mozdev.org/installation.html

On the other hand, if you want to have a simple HTTP server to dump every request, check netcat. It can act as a server among other things.

Answer (score 2):

Here you can find brief tutorial with screenshot.

http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-monitor-http-communication-in-eclipse.html?page=1

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to point out that **HttpFox** does indeed work on Firefox 4.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/httpfox/